# C# pointer reference

Tags: c#, pointers

Is there a way to create c++ style pointer in c#? I need this to set an int in several places when I don't know which int it is.
Like in c++ I would do:

```
int *i;
if(cond0) i = &someint;
if(cond1) i = &otherint;
if(cond2) i = &thirdint;

if(cond3) *i = someval;
if(cond4) *i = otherval;
if(cond5) *i = thirdval;
```

If I do this in c# style I will need 9 ifs and my program has much more conditions so its not feasible.
I thought of make some sort of value like:

```
int val;
if(cond3) val = someval;
if(cond4) val = otherval;
if(cond5) val = thirdval;

if(cond0) someint = val;
if(cond1) otherint = val;
if(cond2) thirdint = val;
```

but it's not possible because cond3, 4 and 5 are scattered along the program.

Comment: Have you thought about making a class that wraps an `int`?

Answer (score 2):

It is, but you have to wrap any code that does it in an [unsafe block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chfa2zb8%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Alternatively, if this is happening in a method then you might be able to use the ['ref' keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to pass a parameter in by reference.

Both of these options really constrain the solution to method boundaries.  If you're dealing with anything more scattered than that, in C# it's probably better to try and find ways to reorganize your code to use less global state instead.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a type called IntPtr which I use for Windows handles.

Comment: I use it too but it can only take unmanaged values addresses, not managed values addresses.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's an example of C# pointers](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rajeshvs/PointersInCSharp11112005051624AM/PointersInCSharp.aspx) that illustrates both their declaration and how to wrap them in an [unsafe block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chfa2zb8%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Also, see the [C# Programming Guide - Pointer Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y31yhkeb%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you provided enough information in your question to give a correct answer, but one possible solution is to set the values in a function using ref parameters.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var i = 1;
        var someint = 2;
        var otherint = 3;
        var thirdint = 4;

        Console.WriteLine("i: {0}\nsomeint: {1}\notherint: {2}\nthirdint: {3}", i, someint, otherint, thirdint);
        SetInts(true, false, false, false, false, false, ref i, ref someint, ref otherint, ref thirdint);
        Console.WriteLine("i: {0}\nsomeint: {1}\notherint: {2}\nthirdint: {3}", i, someint, otherint, thirdint);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void SetInts(bool cond0, bool cond1, bool cond2, bool cond3, bool cond4, bool cond5, ref int i, ref int someint, ref int otherint, ref int thirdint)
    {
        if (cond0) i = someint;
        if (cond1) i = otherint;
        if (cond2) i = thirdint;

        if (cond3) i = someint;
        if (cond4) i = otherint;
        if (cond5) i = thirdint;
    }
}
```